# how to Fixed number of digit Textbox of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

For the employee ID. Our Company have 6 fixed numbers of digits so I have to  fixed 6 digits in text box not less than 6 or not less than 5 by using asp.net(If possible by property validation)

So user able to put only 6 number in that particulate text box.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `MaxLength="6"` should do it (on the aspx page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using RegularExpression Validator.. with the following expression:

```
^\d{6}$
```

Comment: Thank you guys. My previous comment didn't upload :)